# SQL Server 2005 Assembly Cast Invalid

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, assemblies, types

I'm trying to call my assemblys SP and receive the following error:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "Pmt_ImportJournal": 
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidCastException: 
   at JournalImport.Pmt_ImportJournal(Int32 orderno)
```

My SP in the assembly is defined like so:

```
[SqlProcedure(Name = "Pmt_ImportJournal")]
public static void Pmt_ImportJournal(int orderno)
```

Should I be using the SQL* datatypes instead of simply an int in the signature? For example SqlInt32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check inside the Pmt_ImportJournal method.  Some line of code inside there is likely to be raising the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the signature of the stored procedure that is created?  Also, is it possible that there's a cast error farther down in your method?